# Inline If else in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="alcohol">
       <img src="~/img/Interaction/alcohol.png" title="Alcohol" />
       <span>{{product.interaction}}</span>
  </div>
```

IF `{{product.interaction}} == 'CAUTION'` means Span color is red  any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-style` with a conditional (*ternary*) operator that checks for some string and gives a specific style. Here is what it looks like:

```
<span ng-style="product.interaction=='CAUTION' ? {color:'red'} : ''">
  {{product.interaction}}
</span>
```

---

(for *else*, to add color white)

Simply extend the else clause

```
<span ng-style="product.interaction=='CAUTION' ? {color:'red'} : {color:'white'}">
  {{product.interaction}}
</span>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.product = {};
  $scope.product.interaction = "CAUTION";
  $scope.product.interaction2 = "ANYTHING"; // to show `else` variation
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="alcohol">
      <span ng-style="product.interaction2=='CAUTION' ? {color:'red'} : {color:'white'}">
        {{product.interaction2}}
      </span>
      
      <span ng-style="product.interaction=='CAUTION' ? {color:'red'} : {color:'white'}">
        {{product.interaction}}
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: else means white how to add ? @Aleksey Solovey

Comment: ternary operator has this syntax: `condition ? expression_if_true : expression_if_false`, the _false_ one is your _else_